# Laravel Multi Level Relationships with Corresponding Table Relating to Parent

Tags: laravel

Apologies if the Title is confusing, but let me try clarify.
I have a table of **students** followed by a table of **processes** which has a *child table* of **process tasks**. I want to then, for each student, have a corresponding record of for each process, and similarly, a corresponding record for each process task.

eg:

```
Student ABC
Student DEF
Student GHI

Process 1: Enter Student Process
    - Process Task: Enter his name
    - Process Task: Phone the student
    - Process Task: Upload his photo

Process 2: Something else
    - Process Task: Tick this
    - Process Task: Tick that
```

So that I can then have set "to do lists" (processes and their relevant tasks) each with their respective statuses for each student.

***(Simplified) Tables***

```
Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('student_name',64);
        $table->string('student_surname',64);
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('processes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('process')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('process_tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('process_id')->unsigned()->index('process_id_index');
        $table->string('process_task')->nullable();
        $table->integer('sequence'); // task order
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('process_student', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigInteger('student_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('process_id')->unsigned();
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->unsigned()->nullable(); // eg: awaiting feedback, due, etc
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('student_id', 'ps_student_id_foreign')->references('id')->on('students')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('process_id', 'ps_process_id_foreign')->references('id')->on('processes')->onDelete('cascade');
    });

    Schema::create('process_task_student', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigInteger('student_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('process_task_id')->unsigned();
        $table->boolean('complete')->default(0); // eg: awaiting feedback, due, etc
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('student_id', 'spt_student_id_foreign')->references('id')->on('students')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('process_task_id', 'spt_process_task_id_foreign')->references('id')->on('process_tasks')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

***Models / Relationships***

**Process**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'process'
];

public function tasks() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProcessTask');
}
```

**Process Task**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'process_id',
    'process_task',
    'sequence'
];
```

**Student**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'id','student_name','student_surname'
];

public function processes() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Process')->withTimestamps();
}

public function tasks() {
    return $this->processes()->belongsToMany('App\ProcessTask')->withTimestamps();
}
```

//Edit : Added further code for clarification

Controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $student = Student::with(['processes','processes.tasks'])->findOrFail($id);
    return view('students.show', compact('student'));
}
```

View:

```
@foreach ($student->processes as $student_process)
@foreach ($student_process->tasks->sortBy('sequence') as $student_process_task)
    <div class="kt-widget2__item kt-widget2__item--primary">
      <div class="kt-widget2__checkbox">
        <label class="kt-checkbox kt-checkbox--solid kt-checkbox--single">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="kt-widget2__info">
        <a href="#" class="kt-widget2__title">
            {{$student_process_task->process_task}}
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

I feel I am going wrong with my relationships? How would I get the process, its relevant tasks for a specific student?

Answer (score 0):

So you have many-to-many relations between students and processes, but one-to-many between processes and tasks. But you also have a pivot table for process-tasks relations. I'm confused. First, make sure you add reverse relations since I don't see any. If process-task is many-to-many change hasMany to belongsToMany. Long story short, please double-check that you structured all relations correctly. Then go to StudentController.php and

```
public function index()
{
  return Student::with("processes.tasks")->get();
}
```

Search for "nested eager loading" in this page https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships for more information.

Comment: Process hasMany Tasks - as shown in the example. That is the 'to do list' itself, then each student has a "copy" of each such process/task. For example: I need to lookup "Student ABC" and see what his `status` is of "Process 1: Enter Student Process" and what the `complete` value is of "Process Task: Enter his name"

To clarify, a ProcessTask "belongsTo" a Process (since it will only belong to a single process).

Comment: My mistake. By looking at its name, I thought "process_task" is a pivot table (muscle memory). But the other parts of my answer should be correct. So define reverse relations and update your index function.

Comment: That doesnt do the trick though because referencing ```@foreach ($student->processes as $student_process)``` refers to the ```process_student``` pivot table (correct). However, ```@foreach ($student_process->tasks->sortBy('sequence') as $student_process_task)``` is referencing the ```tasks``` table, not the ```process_task_student` pivot table?

Comment: You don't need any direct relation between students and tasks, so "process_task_student" pivot table. Student and Process models have many-to-many relations. Process and Task models have one-to-many relations. This means you can reach tasks over process from Student controller. There are plenty of ways to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following - perhaps you could update your answer to reflect what you mean and show the controller side of things and show a use case in the View?